# Context menu becomes unclickable above HTML video layer

Tags: javascript, html, css, contextmenu

I have created a custom context menu and would like it to be served as a playlist for my project.

However it becomes unclickable over my video frame.

[image]

Is this the nature of HTML video tag?

Here's my snippet

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dee</title>
<style type="text/css">
 *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  html, body, .container{
    height: 100%;
  }

  body{
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 10px;
  }

  .container{
    background: #f6f6f6;
  }

  .context-menu {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
  }

  .context-menu ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
  }

  .context-menu ul li:not(.separator){
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .context-menu ul li:hover{
    /*background: #eee;*/
    background: #fff;
    border-left: 4px solid #666;
  }

  .separator{
    height: 1px;
    background: #dedede;
    /*background: #fff;*/
    margin: 2px 0 2px 0;
  }

  .videoClass{
    background: #fff;
    border-color: #fff;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" oncontextmenu="return showContextMenu(event);">
    <div id="contextMenu" class="context-menu">
      <ul>
        <li>List</li>
        <li>List</li>
        <li>List</li>
        <li class="separator"></li>
        <li>List</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <video id="myVideo" class="videoClass" controls width="500" src="trailer.mp4"></video>
  </div>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onclick = hideContextMenu;
    window.onkeydown = listenKeys;
    var contextMenu = document.getElementById('contextMenu');

    function showContextMenu(){
      contextMenu.style.display = 'block';
      contextMenu.style.left = event.clientX + 'px';
      contextMenu.style.top = event.clientY + 'px';
      return false;
    }

    function hideContextMenu(){
      contextMenu.style.display = 'none';
    }

    function listenKeys(event){
      var keyCode = event.which || event.keyCode;
      if (keyCode == 27) { //27 means escape key
        hideContextMenu();
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## New Answer

I found that an even simpler solution to your problem exists. If you just put the video tag before the context menu, that does the trick:

```
<video id="myVideo" class="videoClass" controls width="500" src="trailer.mp4"></video>
<div id="contextMenu" class="context-menu">
    <ul>
      <li>List</li>
      <li>List</li>
      <li>List</li>
      <li class="separator"></li>
      <li>List</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

## Original Answer

In my limited experience I haven't loved using z-indexes, so I'll look for another solution, but I put styles of `z-index: 1` on video class and `z-index: 2` on the context menu class, and that did that trick (in chrome at least, I didn't try any other browsers).